# Pythagorean Type Equation

Tags: diophantine-equations, pythagorean-triples

$4a^2+b^2=2c^2$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive integers.
I have to find all primitive triplets such that $c \le N$. $N$ can be as high as $10^7$. Can we get a tree like solutions like that of pythagorean triplets, which efficiently generate only the primitive solutions?

If $(p,q,r)$ is a primitive solution, then $(p,3q+4r,2q+3r)$ is also a primitive solution.

EDIT:
In this case the whole square triplet form arithmetic progression. What if this is not the case? For example how to solve $a^2+3b^2=c^2$?

Comment: For $a^2+3b^2=c^2$, Euler's $6n+1$ Theorem (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eulers6nPlus1Theorem.html)  should help.

Comment: It looks like all prime factors of $a$ must be of the form $12k+1$ or $12k-1$. And $c$ can be expressed as $x^2+xy+y^2$ where $(x,y)=1$. But it doesn't help much to find the solutions.

Comment: There can be no primitive solutions because you have two of the terms as even numbers. In a primitive Pythagorean triple, two of a,b,c must be odd.

Comment: There are no primitive solutions because two of a,b,c must be odd but, over all integers, you might try  $a\in\mathbb{Z}, b=\pm2a, c=\pm2a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer addresses the question as originally posted, relating to the equation $4a^2+b^2=2c^2$ only.*

Putting $d=2a$ we have $d^2+b^2=2c^2$, implying that $b^2,c^2,d^2$ are in arithmetic progression.

Formulae for generating sets of three squares in arithmetic progression with no common divisor (due to Leonardo of Pisa (Fibonacci)) may be found [here](http://math.ucr.edu/~res/math153/history07b.pdf).  The formulae are in terms of parameters $m,n$ which must be coprime yielding two cases: a) one even, one odd; b) both odd.

For case (a) the formulae are: $m^2+2mn-n^2, m^2+n^2, n^2+2mn-m^2$. This yields odd values so would produce a non-integer value for $a = d/2$.

For case (b) the above formulae yield even values so they must be divided by $2$ to yield coprime values.  For our purposes, however, we do not need $b,c,d$ to be coprime; the requirement is for $a,b,c$ to be coprime. So the formulae we require are:

$$a=\frac{d}{2}=\frac{m^2+2mn-n^2}{2}$$

$$c=m^2+n^2$$

$$b=n^2+2mn-m^2$$

Note that $a$ must be odd since $m^2+2mn-n^2\equiv1+2-1 \equiv 2$ mod $4$.

For some values of $m,n$, these formulae will yield a negative value for $a$ or $b$. To ensure positive values therefore the complete solution is:

$$a=\Bigg\lvert\frac{m^2+2mn-n^2}{2}\Bigg\rvert$$

$$b=\lvert n^2+2mn-m^2\rvert$$

$$c=m^2+n^2$$

Comment: Thanks @Adam Bailey. I can generate all solutions efficiently. We have to remove $n < m$ condition to get all the solutions. Otherwise we have to count carefully to include those extra solutions. For example, $(7,2,10)$ is a valid solution which is generated by $(m,n)=(2,1)$.

Comment: Edited to address negative values.  For $(7,2,10)$ we have $(m,n)=(3,1)$.